# Margin notes in listing with float environment – Error: Float(s) lost

Tags: floats, listings, marginpar, marginnote

Based on this question: [Margin notes in listing with float environment – Error: Float(s) lost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256446) I have now other question. The solution is working fine.

But I want to use floats for listings, to prevent page breaks inside the code (~ 30 lines). By using floats I get an error:

```
 ! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.
```

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=C++,numbers=left,escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}, float, floatplacement=H}

\begin{lstlisting}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
 cout << i << endl;(*@\marginpar{margin note}@*)
}
\end{lstlisting}

%% I've tried to wrap \marginnote with boxes, but could't fix it.

\begin{lstlisting}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
cout << i << endl;(*@\marginpar{margin note}@*)
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

By setting listing in `minipage` environment does not solve the problem.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It was the same as in ohter question with ``float`` difference.

Comment: you cannot have flosts inside floats. `\marginpar` is a type of float.

Comment: But what should be then the solution for the problem described in referenced post? If i use ``float`` environment and ``\marginnote`` that building fine, but with the problem described in other post. And ``\marginpar`` render it well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot nest floating environments; `\marginpar`'s are floats.  You can define a command to mimic a `marginpar` by making it non-floating and invisible:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,calc}
\lstset{language=C++,numbers=left,escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}

\newcommand*{\marginnote}[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \makebox[\linewidth+\marginparsep][l]{}%
    \parbox[t][0pt][t]{1\marginparwidth}{#1}%
  }%
}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[float, floatplacement=t]
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
(*@\marginnote{margin note}@*)cout << i << endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\noindent\mbox{}

\begin{lstlisting}[float, floatplacement=h]
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
(*@\marginnote{margin\\ note}@*)    cout << i << endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> [image]